# Why I still have to wait for while loop when using async-await syntax?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, while-loop, async-await

I am trying to understand the `async-await` syntax deeply. So I write some code to illustrate what I know about `async-await`. Here is my code:

```js
doSomething();
doFirst();

async function doSomething() {
 const result = await stackUp();
 console.log(result);
}

function doFirst() {
 console.log('first');
}

function stackUp() {
 let counter = 0;
 while (counter < 4000000000) {
  counter++;
 }
 return counter;
}
```

I called `doSomething()` then `doFirst()`. The `while loop` is used to delay the process. The console logs out `first` then `4000000000` as intended.  To what I understand so far, `first` should be consoled out immediately then wait for `stackUp()` to finish counting and `4000000000` will be next. But the problem is  `first` isn't consoled out immediately. I still have to wait for `stackUp()` to finish then both will be logged out. If I use `setTimeout()` to delay, everything works fine. Is this happens because `while loop` runs in JavaScript runtime and blocked the code?

Comment: Yep, that’s why it happens. `await` pauses the function that contains it and tells a promise to resume it – it doesn’t start threads or anything. If you don’t involve a promise at all, like in this case, it does nothing.

Comment: Is there a way for me to run the while loop asynchronously?

Comment: If Node.js, in a separate process using cluster or child_process, or using `--experimental-worker` and `worker_threads.Worker`. If browser, using a web worker. (You *can* also just yield to the event loop occasionally while doing work, but that’s usually not a good idea.)

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async await doesn't actually let you multithread your JS code. It still all runs synchronously by default, but anything awaited will be attached to the callback of the promise it awaits. If you want to run JS truly multithreaded, you would have to place your code running outside the main thread in a webworker and await a promise based on communications with the webworker.

TLDR; You can't multithread JS directly

Answer (score 0):

Async/Await behaves like synchronous code execution that why its console both the output at the same time.

Async method execution goes to the callback queue.The callback queue works with the event loop in executing the callback functions.

Non-callback functions (doFirst) will go to main call stack.

After the code execution of main call stack , it will execute the callback queue with the help of Event loop,  if Callback queue has codes to execute then it pops the message from it to the Main Stack for the execution.